# Connecting oracle database using spark with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, kerberos

My jdbc is connected to oracle database using **krb5loginmodule** without any issue, by giving keytab file or ticket cache.But, due to performance, I want to connect my oracle database using Spark. If I use simple username and password, I am able to connect my spark application to Oracle database using below snippet:

```
Dataset<Row> empDF = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/1234@//127.0.0.1:1522/orcl")
            .option("dbtable", "hr.employees")
            //.option("user", "hr")
            //.option("password", "1234")
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
            .load();
empDF.printSchema();
empDF.show();
```

Now, how can I enable Kerberos authentication using keytab, instead of using a hardcoded username and password? I don't want to use a ticket cache by manually doing kinit.

Comment: Did you find the way?

Answer (score 0):

Hellow!
I have a solution, but it is written in python:

```py
url = """jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
    (ENABLE = BROKEN)
    (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (LOAD_BALANCE = OFF) 
      (FAILOVER = ON) 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.ru)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1.ru)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = serverOCI)
    )
  )"""

connectionProperties = {
    "jdbc.auth.principal" : "username",
    "oracle.net.kerberos5_cc_name": "/tmp/krb5cc_1119238290",
    "oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication":"true",
    "oracle.net.authentication_services": "KERBEROS5",
    "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
}

props = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
props.putAll(connectionProperties)
q = "(select * from dual)"

spark.read.jdbc(url, q, properties=props).limit(10).show()
```